# Why [^\d\w\s,] matches "leonardo,davinci"?

Tags: regex, grep

I can't understand why the regexp:

```
[^\d\s\w,]
```

Matches the string:

```
"leonardo,davinci"
```

That is my test:

```
$ echo "leonardo,davinci" | egrep '[^\d\w\s,]'
leonardo,davinci
```

While this works as expected:

```
$ echo "leonardo,davinci" | egrep '[\S\W\D]'
$
```

Thanks very much

Comment: @blueygh2 the whole thing is negated. It may be something to do with egrep, never used it.

Comment: @blueygh2 Normally `^` negates everything in the list between brackets. I don't see how that regex could possibly match that string though. As far as I see you are only matching one character, which is not a digit, spatial character or word character.

Comment: Side note, `[\d\w]` is redundant: `\w = [a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Comment: With [grep -P](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#grep-Programs): *Interpret the pattern as a Perl regular expression*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because `egrep` doesn't have the predefined sets `\d`, `\w`, `\s`. Therefore, putting slash in front of them is just matching them literally:

> **leonar**d**o**,d**avinci**

```
echo "leonardo,davinci" | egrep '[^a-zA-Z0-9 ,]'
```

Will indeed, not match.

---

If you have it installed, you can use `pcregrep` instead:

```
echo "leonardo,davinci" | pcregrep '[^\w\s,]'
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

The same problem there is with the tab?

It doesn't recognize [^\t] as "all except tab", but as "all except t"...

Comment: @Nopaste, right. It fails for `\t` too: `echo -e 'foo\tbar' | egrep '\t'` yields no matches.